# RapidMiner 6 installation issue

Tags: java, windows, installation, 64-bit, rapidminer

I have installed java 7 (also tried java 8) on my system, then installed Rapidminer 6 on my system. All installations were fine. Now when I tried to launch Rapidminer Studio, it has given me the error i.e.
*Java could not be launched. Probably there is not enough free memory available. Please close all other applications and try again. Errorcode: 1*

Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Probably there is not enough free memory available.

Comment: @chiastic-security I have 69GB free memory available in C drive

Comment: That's hard drive space, not RAM.

Comment: I have total of 4GB of RAM installed on my laptop, Can I install Rapidminer with this RAM?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with RapidMiner 7.1 (i have 8GB of RAM). I don't know what the problem is, but for me the RapidMiner-Studio.bat file in the RM folder worked.